# All white Ionic Framework with child views

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

This is my code:

$stateProvider

```
.state('tabs', {
    url: '/tabs',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
})

.state('tabs.personal', {
url: '/personal',
    views: {
        'personalGoals': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/personalGoals.html',
          controller: 'personalCtrl'
        }
    }
});

// if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tabs/personal');
```

the screen is all white except the tabs, when running in ionic serve although I copy pasted codes from the tabs template(I used blank to learn from scratch)...

I have templates/tabs.html, templates/personalGoals.html as some files needed to render...

Comment: You state config is correct, maybe you should check whether add links to your  personal page in tabs.html or not. Regards!

Comment: What do you mean "add links"?

Comment: Could you add your tabs.html code?

Comment: fortunately I figured it out... I added my answer at the bottom... :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out...

```
.state('tabs.personal', {
url: '/personal',
    views: {
        'personalGoals-view': { 
          templateUrl: 'templates/personalGoals.html',
          controller: 'personalCtrl'
        }
    }
});


<ion-tab title="Personal" icon-off="ion-person" icon-on="ion-person" href="#/personal">
    <ion-nav-view name="personalGoals-view"></ion-nav-view> 
</ion-tab>
```

The key is the words "personalGoals-view"... :D